# C++ on objective-c can not read .stl file

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I'm writing an iOS app with OpenGLES and try to load a binary stl model file by C++.

I have a model file "model.stl" and I try to use fopen and ifstream to open the file, but the return value are both null. If I changed the extension of the model file to .txt, then it succeed. However, I think this is not a good solution.

```
myFile.open(path.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
if (!myFile)
    printf("fstream open fail\n");
```

The code above will print the error message if I load "model.stl", but if I load "model.txt", then it succeed.

Comment: Do you have "model.stl" or "model.txt" in your project?

Comment: Yes, it is in my supporting files folder